# Increase in memory usage while reading http response

Tags: go

I am working on a tool where I have 300 routines that are downloading a file from a public cloud. All routines are parallely downloading the file block by block (api's supported by cloud). I initially create a file of given size and the memory map it. 
Now I am reading the response body directly into the memory mapped byte slice using the io.ReadFull api. With this, memory eventually spikes to 100%.

Comment: I am a bit confused. You are storing what you download in memory and memory usage is therefore high, correct? Now I am not sure what your question is. Could you please clarify what you are trying to archive?

Comment: Leon, I am reading the response into the memory mapped byte slice. I have edited the question's body. Reading the response directly into memory mapped byte slice should not increase the memory usage if I am not wrong.

Comment: If you are using the `mmap` syscall, then the behavior is probably system, or at-least OS specific. Maybe you can pass some flags to `mmap` to get the kernel not remove old data from memory, but I do not know enough to give you this answer. Maybe also add the code you use to create your memory mapped slices in the question.

Comment: added the code.

Comment: I still don't see the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I concern, the copy move  is just like you allocate a new array and copy elements into it, the memory will be double size of the initial array. By the way, after read data from http response body, you should close it, like:

```
defer resp.Body.Close()
```